# OleDbConnection failed creating a new excel file

Tags: excel, oledbconnection

I have to use OleDbConnection to create a new excel file, but when I open connection with this string:

```
OleDbConnection excelConnection =
                new OleDbConnection(
                    String.Format(
                        @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";",
                        excelFile));
```

I receive an error that in english sounds like "The outer table is not in the expected format."

But the file is NEW and empty ... how can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed to [ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/) library, and now it works.